# Can I use a JQuery Variable to select MYSQL column?

Tags: php, mysql

When one of my forms (name= `QuestionTypeSelector` value=`AddingFractions`) posts, the following snippet of PHP is part of the code that runs:

```
$QuestionTypeSelector = $_POST['QuestionTypeSelector'];
 $db->query(" UPDATE answers SET QuestionType = '$QuestionTypeSelector' WHERE user_id=$id");
```

`$_POST['QuestionTypeSelector']` successfully returns `AddingFractions` and this successfully sets `$QuestionTypeSelector` = `AddingFractions`. In turn, this sets a column titled `QuestionType` equal to `AddingFractions`.

Instead of this, I want to set a column titled `AddingFractionsScore` equal to `2`. I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
$QuestionTypeSelector = $_POST['QuestionTypeSelector'];
 $db->query(" UPDATE answers SET '$QuestionTypeSelector+Score' = '2' WHERE user_id=$id");
```

In other words, I'm trying to use the JQuery variable to select the column. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `"UPDATE answers SET '{$QuestionTypeSelector}Score' = '2' WHERE user_id=$id";`

Comment: Thanks, @AlexTartan. If you post that as a response, I'll be happy to "accept" it

Answer (score 0):

Sure

```
$col = $_POST['QuestionTypeSelector'] . 'Score';
$db->query("UPDATE answers SET '$col' = '2' WHERE user_id=$id");
```

Answer (score 0):

This process is very dangerous because you might be victim of sql injection. 
I suggest you to use a mapping array to select your column. 
Es. 
Your jQuery post a integer in a variable POST
$_POST['column'] = 0;
Then in your php page, you get the post value and use it ad key to retrieve the column name

```
$availableColumns = array(
    'QuestionTypeSelector',
    'QuestionTypeSelector1,
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, @DavidGinanni. I'm completely new to coding, so  I'm not savvy when it comes to sql injection. The form only has radio buttons; there aren't any text inputs where a user could inject sql code. Am I still vulnerable?

Comment: Yes, if you use your variables that comes from get/post request without checking it, you are always vulnerabile.https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/